# Auto number rows of a table that was created using Jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, for-loop, html-table

I need to auto number the rows in a table. The total number of rows in the table varies and it is saved in a variable called 'Total'.

The table is :

```
    <script>

    var table = '<table border="1" id="tblTestCases">';

   table += "<tr bgcolor='#e6e6e6'><td align=center colspan='3'>Number of text boxes = " + $searchObject.find('[type=text]').length + "</td></tr>";
$searchObject.find('[type=text]').each(function () {
table += "<tr bgcolor='#ccccff'><td>Name of textbox = " + $(this).attr("name") + "</td><td> ID =" + $(this).attr("id") + "</td></tr>";
});

table += "<tr bgcolor='#e6e6e6'><td align=center colspan='3'>Number of Submit Buttons = " + $searchObject.find('[type=submit]').length + "</td></tr>";
$searchObject.find('[type=submit]').each(function () {
table += "<tr bgcolor='#6666ff'><td>Name of Submit button = " + $(this).attr("name") + "</td><td> ID =" + $(this).attr("id") + "</td></tr>";

table += "<tr bgcolor='#e6e6e6'><td align=center colspan='3'>Number of Telephone entry fields = " + $searchObject.find('[type=tel]').length + "</td></tr>";
$searchObject.find('[type=tel]').each(function () {
table += "<tr bgcolor='#ccccff'><td>Name of Telephone entry field button = " + $(this).attr("name") + "</td><td> ID =" + $(this).attr("id") + "</td></tr>";
});


    //more table rows here...

    $("#tableDiv").html(table+"</table>");

    </script>
```

I need the Serial number to appear infront of all the table rows.

Can anyone help me with the code? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Creating an element using string manipulation is not a very good idea and performance is not good as well. Why don't you use some template engine (liek handlebar) and create an object array for that template. This will give much more clean solution

Comment: What about this?  $('#tblTestCases tr').each(function (i) {
     var td = "<td>"+i+"</td>" ;
       $(this).prepend($(td));
     });